# How to highlight a certain continent in google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to highlight a certain continent in google map by some color.

I read about Polygon, but what i need is just determine continent name.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use draw a [polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polygons) over the desired area. To do this, you'll need the coordinate data for whatever you want to overlay. There are various tools and resources online which can help you get that data, like [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php).

Alternatively, you can apply a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay) to the area you wish to highlight. You place an image onto your map at a defined location. The image will rotate, tilt, or zoom along with your map. You can also set the transparency of the image, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I tried polygon and it is ok, but I will try groundoverlay. I think this will be better.